# EF keeps telling me there is no InsertFunction for entity from DB that has Identity set?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, dbcontext, ef-database-first

Application uses Entity Framework 4.1 with database first approach.

I have in database a simple table for logging purposes:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LogEntrys](
    [LogEntryID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetime] NULL,
    [Message] [varchar](5000) NULL,
    [IP] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [UserName] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [Controller] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Action] [varchar](50) NULL
)
```

It translates ok in model into EntitySet 'LogEntrys' and Entity LogEntry.
Problem is, when i try to insert something into the table from applicatio i get the following error:

> Unable to update the EntitySet 'LogEntrys' because it has a DefiningQuery and no  element exists in the  element to support the current operation.

I have seen similar posts on SO and i have tried to solve it by editing the XML edmx file like explained in this tip: [MSDN blog tip 34](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/09/01/tip-34-how-to-work-with-updatable-views.aspx), I have removed the Defining query. The key was already set up as it should be.

but then i get the following error:

> "Invalid object name 'AMSModelStoreContainer.LogEntrys'."

I am not sure what is the problem, and/or what i am doing wrong?

any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the no field is set as primary key create your table like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LogEntrys](
    [LogEntryID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetime] NULL,
    [Message] [varchar](5000) NULL,
    [IP] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [UserName] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [Controller] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Action] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_LogEntrys] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LogEntryID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and then update your model. You might need to completely remove the old one entry you had for it in your .edmx and re=add it now that you have tinkered with it.

Comment: Ok, i was an idiot...i have made identity and not the primary key...what confused me was that i saw the key icon in EF dbmx, but i have completely forgotten to click the key in SSMS...
Thank You!

Comment: no problem sometimes it just takes a fresh set of eyes with these things. If you dont have a primary key I believe entity framework just best guesses one...